# Is it possible to decorate methods in scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

So, I have an object, with methods, something like that:

```
object Connector {

  def createObject (id : Long, x : Double, y : Double, name : String, objtype : Int, layer : String) : String  = {
    //some code
  }

  def deleteObject (id : Long) : String  = {
    //some code
  }

  def findObject (name : String) : String  = {
    //some code
  }

  //some other methods
}
```

And for example, I'd like to handle errors in all methods, with same code like:

```
var res = domethod(methodParams)
if (res.indexOf("Error") > 0){
  doSomeOtherMethod() //that can fix error
  res = domethod(methodParams) //with same params
}
return res
```

Is there way in Scala, to handle errors like this, and without code duplication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a private function to handle your errors:

```
private def tryUnsafe(f: => String): String = {
  var res = f()
  if (res.indexOf("Error") > 0){
    doSomeOtherMethod() //that can fix error
    res = f()
  }
  return res
}
```

You can just call `tryUnsafe` like this:

```
tryUnsafe {
  // code that eventually return a String
}
```

Edit: adding details to address the first comment.

You can use `tryUnsafe` in your functions like this:

```
def createObject (id : Long, x : Double, y : Double, name : String, objtype : Int, layer : String) : String  = {
  tryUnsafe {
    // the code to create an object, that returns a String
  }
}
```

When answering your question I assumed that
*  `domethod` was a placeholder for `createObject`, `deleteObject`, etc
*  `doSomeOtherMethod` was the same for all `domethod`s and not a specific one per operation, if it's not the case, you can take a `g` parameter in addition to `f` to call in your `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, that's better. I suspect doSomeOtherMethod needs to be abstracted out too

Comment: `f` is not a by-name param in your example. `f: => String` would be.

Comment: @ghik you're right :) I had it by name in my first version, but then Paul pointed out that I missed the second call. I then turned it into a function so that it can be invoked a second time.  Editing.

Comment: `var` isn't much necessary here - `def tryUnsafe(...) = {val res1 = f(); if (res1.blabla) {doSomeOtherMethod(); f()} else res1 }`

Comment: @vptheron by-name param is evaluated every time you refer to it, so it can be evaluated more than once. In runtime, there is no difference between `() => T` and `=> T`. Also, if you use `() => T`, you'll have to do this: `tryUnsafe { () => /* ... */ }`